# The navigation links on my tumblr sidebar don't work?

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, tumblr, sidebar

In my tumblr theme that I'm creating, I've run into some issues. I have my sidebar, and in the sidebar are my navigation links, but they don't seem to work. They're customisable and I can change the colour of them. The 'reblog' and 'notes' links work and do what they're meant to do but my 'home' archive' and 'ask' links don't work. They show up, but they don't actually work.

I'm not a professional, but I've looked over the code and I'm not too sure what's wrong. I've tried retyping the quotation marks and that doesn't help either. Here is a link to the code: http://pastebin.com/uEpMp8w3

Just to clarify, the problem is that the navigation links don't work when I click on them. Any ideas why? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As @NeilLunn pointed out, your question needs some work. A link to a live example and what you have tried would be most helpful.

Comment: http://vaedura.tumblr.com/ that's what it looks like. Well I'm not sure what the actual problem is. I've tried retyping ' ' marks and retyping the code. I've looked at other codes to see if I'm making any mistakes but I can't seem to find why my navigation links won't work.